# How to add specific columns for only in *.AUD table not Entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers, acts-as-audited

I have one table and AUD table of this table. But Aud table has two extra columns like "Inserted_Date" and "Insert_By". Main table haven't this two columns. 
"Inserted_Date" column include insert time for AUD table.
"Insert_By" column include user information.
I add these columns in AUD table Entity by manually but this entity doesn't insert any value for these columns. Always insert null.

Also, I write hibernate insert query but these extra columns not in columns.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow merve, first you need to add the examples and how far did you you, together with result and expected. I know it is explained in text but piece of code would help.

Comment: So you added columns to the `_AUD` table but you didn't add them to the entity and setting the values in your business code?  Are you simply wanting to track when an entity was changed and who changed it with Envers?